# Checking kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways while status is kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

How to check in *CLLocationManager* if user has already selected not use *kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways* when current status is *kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse*?
In my case firstly user has agreed to use *kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse*. Also I have some switch to use location manager in background so I propose to user to use background mode. User turns on the switch, I ask *requestAlwaysAuthorization* and then the user does not confirm to use this mode. How can I check the user selection later to setup the message near the switch for user? Something like "You have disabled using location updates in background".

Answer (score 0):

You can implement CLLocationManagerDelegate's `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` and check for the possibly granted/not granted permissions and save it in the `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: The location manager only reports changes to the authorization status. Nothing will change if user denied on requestAlwaysAuthorization.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that. One thing you can do is the following: You know when you show the authorization dialog, so you can store that in the NSUserDefaults. The next time the user comes to the screen with the switch, you already know that you showed the dialog. If the CLLocation authorization status is not authorized, you know that the user must have declined and you can show the corresponding message.

Comment: Hannes, it's seems to be the decision, but there is another problem which corresponds to the another question probably. If I have never showed the requestAlwaysAuthorization and if current state is kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied (when user has been disabled location in per application setting) i have to make requestAlwaysAuthorization which will firstly show the system dialog for user. But in this case I don't know  should I run requestAlwaysAuthorization or should I show alert that "Location service is disabled".

Comment: I think it's an easy decision: If the status is "NotDetermined" or "AuthorizedWhenInUse" then you run the requestAlwaysAuthorization, if it's "Denied" you show an alert with an option to authorize. This option would take him to the app settings via UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)

Comment: Yes. But it is not so friendly, because user denied the WhenInUse mode and he did not deny AlwaysAuthorization. In this case he has never seen AlwaysAuthorization system alert. So I have to run requestAlwaysAuthorization even if the state is "Denied" in this case.